# PySpark: save RDD of JSON strings to MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, pyspark

I want to move my spark dataframe to mongoDB and for that I want to use mongoDB connection.

I came up with an RDD of JSON strings (which should be immediate to insert to mongoDB using pyMongo for example).

```
myRDD.take(1)

'{\n  "language": "FRENCH",\n  "id": 358539,\n  "title": "Effet Tetris",\n  "topics": : [\n    {\n      "topic": "VIDEO_GAMES",\n ...
```

However I'm stuck at this point, convering my RDD to a proper DataFrame is not an option since I have repeated and deeply nested fields.

Converting my RDD to a DataFrame with only one column (the JSON string) and then saving it to Mongo will provide a different structure (since the dataframe  will have a name for the column and I will end up with a MongoDB

```
{
   "_id" : ... ,
   "colName" : "myJsonString"
}
```

Which is not what i want.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You said you want to move your spark DataFrame to MongoDB, but also said that you can't convert your RDD to a proper DataFrame. What is your original data source before `myRDD`?

Comment: it's basically a pipeline that produces some very big and nested google protobuffers, so spark won't infer the schema correctly and I won't specify it manually

Comment: Sorry, another question to clarify when you said 'pipeline' are you referring to MongoDB aggregation pipeline or some other pipeline? Because you can use load data into Spark using MongoDB aggregation pipeline. Cheers